# Emission broken in Lit Shader Graph (Unity 2021.2.7f1)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I'm trying to create a simple emissive Lit Shader Graph and I'm coming across several issues.

Emission doesn't appear to work. Not "working bad" or not "unnatural", Bloom has nothing to do with the issue - it's NOT working. Color stays on the Base Color value and Emission value is ignored.
Main Preview of the shader doesn't react to the changes and stays as a dark grey quad (can't change its shape either).

After a quick check, emission on a simple material (without a shader graph) is also ignored.
URP is installed, Post-Processing installed, PPLayer and PPVolume added, Bloom added, PPVolume is global.
Any suggestions ?..